# How to resolve Waiting to reconcile Route. Resource readiness deadline exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

[image]

But my service is working normally.

Comment: @Mofawaw: thanks for wanting to improve questions here. Would you please use Markdown for your edits, and not HTML? Markdown is much easier for future editors to handle.

Comment: Looks like an internal issue in Cloud Run. You can retry.

Comment: @AhmetB - Google How to retry? Do you mean build and push again?

Comment: Also encountered the exact same thing actually.

Comment: Yes, please, try to redeploy, to confirm if this is reproducible. As Ahmet mentioned, this seems to be an internal issue, that should disappear in case you deploy it again.

Comment: same issue from me, i tried to redeploy my service the issue has gone from the screen but after an hour the error appeared again.

Comment: Hi, I see the same issue on services deployed 4 days ago. All services are operating normally but it's a test environment so I don't know how about working under high load

Comment: Confirming this is indeed an internal issue and is being investigated. It should not impact  traffic to your application. For now, it seems re-deploying makes the issue go away.

Comment: thank for answers everyone. I'm try to redeploy my service then solve this problem.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google we have a similar problem but with the text: "Creating revision
Specified version does not exist. Resource readiness deadline exceeded. "

Is this also due to the same internal error?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. Traffic is still flowing, not sure if I want to redeploy.

Comment: Just for more information, is anyone facing this issue for other language based containers than Python?

Comment: @Ady Facing the same issue running a container with aspnetcore.

Comment: We have tried several redeploys and still have this problem.